# How to load/get the KaTeX stylesheet?

Tags: angular, katex

According the katex instruction, I ched if the styleshhet was loaded or not. It wasn't.

Now I am searching for the katex stylesheet to implement into the style.css of angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://katex.org/docs/browser has a `<link rel="stylesheet" …>` in its starter template. While you may be able to download the file from its `href` attribute and copy its contents into your `style.css`, in most situations it would be preferable to just get that tag itself copied to the `index.html` of your Angular project. If you copy the CSS content instead of the link tag, make sure to also get all the files that the stylesheet references, fonts in particular.

Comment: In my app...html I use :  <div class="katex-html"   [innerHTML]="htmll"    >   </div>

Comment: ANd in app.component.ts :   this. htmll = katex.renderToString("c = sqrt{a^2 + b^2}" ); In result the ^2 will be sub not sup position ond sqrt is written as string

Comment: You need a backslash in front of the square root to make it a TeX symbol. Two backslashes inside your steering literal since one of them escapes the other. `"a=\\sqrt{a^2}"`. Wrong position sounds like wrong style. Check developer console whether any loading errors get reported there.

Comment: CONSOLE LOG:     app.component.html:3 WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see https://g.co/ng/security#xss